# Error while extracting field using JsonPath in Scala

Tags: scala, jsonpath

I am trying to extract a data field from a Json string using JsonPath and I am facing a wired problem:

Json string:

```
val message = {"me":"a","m":"1.0","message_metadata":"{"massage":"12542","start_date":"1515"}"}
```

Code:

```
val eventMetaData = JsonPath.read[String](message, "$.message_metadata")
```

When I run this from a host it throws an class not found exception:

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/Predicate
    at com.amazon.isp.execution.notifications.messageHandlers.CosmosNotificationsHandler$$anonfun$2.apply(CosmosNotificationsHandler.scala:164) ~[ScreeningExecutionEngineService-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.isp.execution.notifications.messageHandlers.CosmosNotificationsHandler$$anonfun$2.apply(CosmosNotificationsHandler.scala:153) ~[ScreeningExecutionEngineService-1.0.jar:?]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) ~[scala-library.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.isp.execution.notifications.messageHandlers.CosmosNotificationsHandler.getEventType(CosmosNotificationsHandler.scala:153) ~[ScreeningExecutionEngineService-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.isp.execution.notifications.messageHandlers.CosmosNotificationsHandler.processMessage_aroundBody0(CosmosNotificationsHandler.scala:63) ~[ScreeningExecutionEngineService-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.isp.execution.notifications.messageHandlers.CosmosNotificationsHandler$AjcClosure1.run(CosmosNotificationsHandler.scala:1) ~[ScreeningExecutionEngineService-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.a
```

I not using any Predicate class but still get the error. Please let me know if you faced this kind of problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this library in your build.sbt or your pom.xml like this?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```